# error 429 (too many requests) while trying to set up a webhook for a python telegram bot

Tags: python, flask, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telegram-webhook

I've created a telegram bot using [PyTelegramBotAPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotAPI/), and I'm trying to set up a webhook using flask. I'm trying to test my webhook using ngrok, but each time I fire up the bot I get an error saying I'm sending to many requests to the API..
This is how I've set up the webhook:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
API_KEY="*api key*"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY, parse_mode=None)
SECRET = "1234"

@app.route(f"/{SECRET}", methods=['POST'])
def handle_webhook():
    update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(
        request.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))
    main(update) #This is where I'm trying to hand the webhook update to the bot
    return "ok"

bot.set_webhook(f"*ngrok URL*/{SECRET}")

def main(update):
    bot.process_new_updates([update])
    #Below here is where my bot logic is written

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried importing the time module and inserting sleep commands in various places to try to find what sends so many requests, but nothing changed..

The code for the bot itself shouldnt make more than 3 requests per update, since it handles each message and  performs an action based on what was written. These actions are overall simple and shouldnt cause any kind of loops in the code..

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have reached the free limitations of ngrok, so you should consider opting for their paid plan.

Alternatively, I try narrowlink, which has recently become available. Although this is a self-hosted service and may not offer the exact functionality as ngrok for your use case.However, the developers are very hospitable, and I could obtain a free token to use their servers by sending an email that is available on their GitHub page. You can send them an email to try your luck.